# I cannot see Project Facets in the Project properties. Any idea what must be wrong?

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, spring-mvc, facet

I have opened a new Maven project and have been following the steps provided in this link:
http://tutorial-academy.com/restful-webservice-jersey-maven/

Not able to see project facets in the properties. Any Idea what must be the problem?

Comment: From step 1, which download (its *actual file name*) did you get from eclipse.org?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. After trying bunch of things I realized I was using Eclipse IDE for java developers instead of Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers. :)